# How could I identify the object in the question body?

Tags: mechanisms

[image]

We're building this thing in AutoDesk Inventor and SolidWorks, yet I don't know what it is. Can someone please tell me? Thanks.

Comment: It's a bracket with a vertical offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're building this "thing" as an exercise to expose you to the various aspects of the software. As a beginner, you want a challenge in creating the part, but you don't want to be overwhelmed by a complex design.

The part includes a number of radii or fillets, a counter-bored hole as well as an ordinary hole and an offset on the tangs.

The design as pictured could be used for many different applications. I can envision it to provide a bearing mount (the counter-bored hole) for an axle. The offset conventional hole would permit the axle to be inset from the mounting surface.

This is one of many possible applications for a very broad and vague design. Beyond the instructional aspect, the application is limited only by one's imagination and understanding of the technical world.

Comment: That's true. We made it in AutoDesk inventor and now we have to make it in solidworks.

Answer (score 1):

It is a Z bracket.

[Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=z%20bracket&rlz=1C1GCEA_enCA851CA851&sxsrf=ACYBGNQyVIUw3sjDhx4SgP4k2X11wypl4A:1569607940286&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8qN6dzfHkAhXJjFkKHaKuAFkQ_AUIEigB&biw=1536&bih=722)